# Control screen and keyboard luminosity in C# on Windows Mobile 6

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, dll, windows-phone

Recently, I begin the development on Windows Mobile 6 (with Visual Studio 2008).

But, I have encountered a problem. I would to control the luminosity of the screen and the keyboard (the device is a Workabout Pro 3).

I have already try several solutions but it doesn't work.

Firstly, I've tried to use the "gdi32.dll" but without success. When I test my application the following error appears :

> "MissingMethodException was unhandled" "DLL PInvoke 'gdi32.dll' not
>   found"

My code :

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern bool SetColorAdjustment(IntPtr hdc, COLORADJUSTMENT lpca);
```

So, I've tried to include this dll in my project (by clicking "Add a reference"), but another error appears :

> "A reference to 'gdi32.dll' could not be added"

Have you got an idea to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution. In my project, I've add the dll "PsionTeklogixNet.dll" as reference.

Now, I can control the luminosity of the screen and of the keyboard!

For screen:

```
using PsionTeklogix.Backlight;
...
if (BacklightControl.IsSupported())
{
     BacklightControl.DisplayBacklightIntensity = lightingScreenTrackBar.Value;
}
```

For keyboard:

```
if (BacklightControl.IsSupported())
{
    BacklightControl.KeyboardBacklightIntensity = lightingKeyboardTrackBar.Value;
}
```